# MySQL : Check condition on two rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck on a pretty simple task.

An image is better than words so here's a sample of my table :

I'd like to retrieve every distinct product_id that are both in groups 27 and 16 for exemple.

So I made this request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM my_table WHERE group_id = 27 AND group_id = 16
```

It's not working and I understand why, but I don't know how to do differently...

I know it's a very noobish question but I don't know what to use in this case, INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do as

```
SELECT product_id FROM my_table WHERE group_id in(27,16)
group by  product_id 
having count(DISTINCT group_id) >= 2
```

Comment: if same product have two entries for same group like 16 then query not worked n op not mentioned any thing related to only single entries for product_id and group_id?? what about it?

Comment: Well in that case replace `having count(*) = 2 ` to `having sum(group_id=27) > 0 and sum(group_id=16)>0`, its sometime better to expand a given answer to some other possibilities/logic instead of eyeing for exact solution, else the door to learn by yourself will never open.

Comment: you can also try in this way:  having COUNT(DISTINCT group_id) >= 2

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m1.product_id 
FROM my_table m1
WHERE m1.group_id = 27
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM my_table m2
              WHERE m1.product_id = m2.product_id
                AND m2.group_id = 16);
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use **`INTERSECT`** but MySQL doesn't support it like: `SELECT product_id 
FROM my_table
WHERE group_id = 27 INTERSECT SELECT product_id 
FROM my_table
WHERE group_id = 16`

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(group_id ORDER BY group_id) As groups
FROM my_table
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING
 FIND_IN_SET('27', groups)
 AND FIND_IN_SET('16', groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM my_table WHERE group_id IN(27,16)